# Ruby script using curl by using rest API(login)

Tags: ruby, rest, curl

I need to create a ruby script using curl by using rest API(developed for login) for some website

Comment: Your question is too broad to be answered. Please visit http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please give some more details. What API, What kind of requests. Why Ruby + Curl? ....

Comment: I need to create a ruby script using curl for below requirement:

Note: This needs to be done by using REST API(which is developed for login validation purpose) in our script.

Currently I need to get REST API from other team, so you can use some generic API and give me script. Once I get correct API, I will replace that.

1.Take Some website URL,provide User ID & Password as input

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest [Net::HTTP](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html). Your code will be like this:

```
require 'net/http'

uri = URI('http://example.com/login')
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri)
request.basic_auth('user', 'pass')

response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port) do |http|
  http.request(request)
end

case response
when Net::HTTPSuccess, Net::HTTPRedirection
  # SUCCESS
else
  # ERROR
end
```

*P.S. Ruby + curl has no sense*